# *.php.html served as php ;/

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I'm using mod_php on apache2 why are `.php.html` pages served as php ?
This breaks the phpdoc output (I have shorttags on and I will keep them on so it parses `<?xml ver[...]?>` as PHP)

How do I force `.php.html` pages to be served as HTML ?

I have

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
```

and in mod conf

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Interesting, I just tried this here and with my setup, fcgid returns a 500 error and logs "communication error" when I create a file named foo.php.html and try to access it (with or without a foo.php file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redhat have know about this issue for a while. Check [this bug post](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=537535) on the issue.

Basically they don't consider it a bug, and from a security point of view they expect the application to handle vetting files.

Answer (score 1):

adding

```
AddHandler text/html .php.html .html
AddType text/html .php.html .html
```

AFTER

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5`

worked -.-'''